# Is there a smarter way of executing this code?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to programming and I'm practising using while loops, I feel like the logic I've used to make this work i.e. for the code to make a request for names to be added to the family tree list and then print it is clumsy.

While I can see that the code works, would there have been a neater way to illicit a request to add more family members without calling the add_member function again within the while loop?

Edit: I am aware that ideally I would have added a parameter to check whether the user entered "no" to stop adding members etc. but that's not the part I'm struggling with.

```
family_tree = []
family_tree.append("Husband")
print("This family includes" + str(family_tree))



def newbie(name):
  family_tree.append(name)

def add_member():
  return input("Would you like to add a new member?").lower()


while add_member() == "yes":
  new_member = input("Enter the name of the Family member")
  newbie(new_member)
  continue 
  add_member()
  break
else:
  print(family_tree)
```

Comment: Everything after `continue` in the loop is ignored.

Comment: Do you know what `continue`, `break`, and `else` do?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 as I said, I'm new to programming, do you have anything useful to add?

Comment: I'm sorry that you think my comment was not useful, but it is actually imperative to have a good grasp on what these keywords do, or else your code will only work by accident, as it does here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is mostly right, but you have some problems.

The `continue` statement skips over the remainder of the loop body, and goes back to the beginning of the loop. It's generally only useful inside an `if`, so that you can skip over parts of the loop conditionally. It you just put it directly in the loop body, it just means that the rest of the loop body will be ignored, so you can simply remove all those statements and the `continue`.

So it should just be:

```
while add_member() == "yes":
    new_member = input("Enter the name of the Family member")
    newbie(new_member)
else:
    print(family_tree)
```

There's also not much point in using `else:` here. You can simply execute that statement after the loop is done.

```
while add_member() == "yes":
    new_member = input("Enter the name of the Family member")
    newbie(new_member)

print(family_tree)
```

The purpose of the `else:` statement in `while` loops is to execute code when the loop finishes *unless* it exits due to a `break` statement. But since there are no break statements in your code, that exception can never occur, and the `print` function would always be called.

Comment: Since there's no more `break` in the `while`, the `else` will always execute. That line can be removed, unindenting the `print()` call by one level.

Answer (score 2):

A simple modification would be this:

```
while True:
  new_member = input("Enter the name of the Family member")
  newbie(new_member)
  if add_member() != "yes":
      break

print(family_tree)
```

Or:

```
keep_going = True
while keep_going:
  new_member = input("Enter the name of the Family member")
  newbie(new_member)
  keep_going = (add_member() == "yes")
else:
  print(family_tree)
```

And so on. There are many ways to rewrite this.

Comment: Your first example doesn't work, even when I corrected the yes to "yes", but the second one does thanks :)

Comment: Oops. Fixed. The logic was wrong (and of course, `"yes"` needed to be a string!)

Comment: Also: I'm aware that I have changed the logic of the code: in your example, you *always* ask first if you want to add a new member (the code in the loop may never be executed), while I actually get in at least once, assuming that you want to add at least one member!

Comment: I appreciate the different approaches, indeed depending on the situation it might be expected that I would want to add a new item in the list for sure thanks.